# Select more than one tables in a query - SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, wpf

I have 3 tables that I need to select 2 columns from each. The tables are called **EmployeeRank1**, **EmployeeRank2** and **EmployeeRank3**. I only know how to select **name** and **pass** property from one of the tables, which is **EmployeeRank1**. However, I need to select **name** and **pass** from all the three tables and join them to a single query. Do you have any suggestions? This is the code I use to select **name** and **pass** from table **EmployeeRank1**:

```
string query = "select * from EmployeeRank1 where Name = @name AND Password = @pass";
```

The idea behind is that if an entry for name and pass matches the one stored in the tables, a seperate window in WPF is opened. This is the code I have:

```
private void EmployeeRank1Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CompanyManagementSystemm.Properties.Settings.ZaimovDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            // create a query and select just the record we need 
            string query = "select * from EmployeeRank1 where Name = @name AND Password = @pass";

            // A local sqlconnection in a using statement ensure proper disposal at the end of this code 
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();

            // Let the database do the work to search for the password and name pair
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pbPassword.Password;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // If the reader has rows then the user/pass exists in the db table
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                EmployeeRank1 employeeRank1 = new EmployeeRank1();
                employeeRank1.Show();
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Are the table related in any way...?  You mentioned *joining* them, shouldn't that be what you do?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results..

Comment: The tables have the exact same fields, such as "name", "pass", "age". However, they have different values for those fields.

Comment: I updated the question with additional information.

Comment: As an aside, unrelated to your question, I notice you're using the db to match password. Frequently, that will mean it's case insensitive, depending on your dbms. Passwords should be case sensitive. Just something to check on.

Answer (score 1):

Do you simply want `union`/`union all`?

```
select name, pass from employeerank1
union 
select name, pass from employeerank2
union
select name, pass from employeerank3;
```

`union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  If there are no duplicates or you do not want them removed, use `union all`.

If you want to look for a name/pass across all three tables, you can use:

```
select *
from (select name, pass from employeerank1
      union all
      select name, pass from employeerank2
      union all
      select name, pass from employeerank3
     ) er
where er.name = @name and er.pass = @pass;
```

Comment: I updated the question, you can look at it for further reference.

Comment: @zaimoff: Did you try to change the value of your `query ` to one of the above string values?